# Hi , i am trying to set the post for 24 hours and with it will be changed

Tags: wp-query, transient

## **Sample Code**

```
$args = [ 
    'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
    'orderby'             => 'rand', 
    'post_type'           => 'post', 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
];
$r= new WP_Query( $args );

if( $r->have_posts() )
{
    while( $r->have_posts() )
    {
        $r->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($q->ID). '">';  the_post_thumbnail();  echo ' </a>';
}
        the_title();
        the_Excerpt();
    }

}
else
{
    _e( 'Sorry no posts found!' );
}
}
```

---

**i also used the transient API but didn't get any help , code with transient is**

```
$args = [ 
    'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
    'orderby'             => 'rand', 
    'post_type'           => 'post', 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
];
$q= new WP_Query( $args );

set_transient( $r, $q, 28800 );

$r = get_transient($code);

if( $r->have_posts() )
{
    while( $r->have_posts() )
    {
        $r->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($q->ID). '">';  the_post_thumbnail();  echo ' </a>';
}
        the_title();
        the_Excerpt();
    }

}
else
{
    _e( 'Sorry no posts found!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish because you lack to point out your goal. But with some guessing I think you are trying to display a post for 24h and then randomly select a new one.

If thats the case, you are using the transient wrong.

```
/** 
 * First, try to check our transient for a daily post id
 */

if ( false === ( $my_post_id = get_transient( 'my_daily_post_id' ) ) ) {

    /**
     * No daily post ID, so create one
     */

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
        'orderby'             => 'rand', 
        'post_type'           => 'post', 
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    );

    $random_posts = get_posts( $args );
    $my_post_id = false;

    if( $random_posts ) {
        foreach( $random_posts AS $random_post ) {
            /**
             * The first on in our randomized array
             */

            $my_post_id = $random_post->ID;
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set a transient for 24h with the post ID
     */

    set_transient( 'my_daily_post_id', $my_post_id, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

} 

/** 
 * Use our 24h post ID to find the post
 */

$args = array( 
    'p' => $my_post_id,
    'post_type'           => 'post', 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $q->have_posts() ) {

    while( $q->have_posts() ) {

        $q->the_post();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($q->ID). '">';  the_post_thumbnail();  echo ' </a>';
        }

        the_title();
        the_excerpt();

    }

} else {
    _e( 'Sorry no posts found!' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much sir :) it is working for now , waiting for next 24 hour to check  whether it changes to new one or not

Comment: @hailey alright. If it works, accept my post as an answer to help others with the same problem :)!

Comment: accepted :) can you please tell me the code of how to make this same post to go on the facebook

Comment: @hailey that's usually not something you explain in 1 line of code ;). Thats a whole new question. You should look into the Facebook API if you want to get started on that.

Comment: can you answer this questionhttps://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263655/i-have-code-that-choose-random-post-after-24-hour-but-i-want-that-same-post-to

Comment: after 24 hour it is saying no post found :(